# Not all dynamically created HTML elements are shown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

There is dynamic data that needs to be looped and create list items.

I am creating HTML element via JQuery and inserting it in HTML.
Below is the code

Dynamic Data:

```
dynamicData = ["qqq","www","eee","rrr","ttt","yyy","uuu","iii"]
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="test-list"></ul>
```

JS:

```
fnData: function (dynamicData) {
    var ele = $('<li/>', {
      class: 'item',
      append:
        '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">click</a>'
    });
    var htmlData = dynamicData.map((item, index) => {
      return ele;
    });
    $('.test-list').html(htmlData);
  }
```

When `fnData` function is triggered `<li>` element is created and using `map` looping trough the dynamic data.
After looping is complete `htmlData` has length of 8 and when `$('.test-list').html(htmlData);` is completed.
Only one `<li>` element appears in the browser output

Not sure why it does not show all 8 `<li>` items

Comment: Don't put the `.` in the `class` attribute. It should be `class="test-list"`. It's only used in selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the same element each time through the loop. An element can only be at one place in the DOM at a time.

You need to create a new element each time. So create the element inside the loop.

```
fnData: function (dynamicData) {
    var htmlData = dynamicData.map((item, index) => {
      return $('<li/>', {
        class: 'item',
        html:
          '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">click</a>'
      });
    });
    $('.test-list').html(htmlData);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar... Something new I learnt, each time it needs to be a new element. Got it